# Ruby: Use module method inside a class method

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

How do we use a module method inside a class method without extending the module?

```
module TestModule
  def module_method
    "module"
  end
end

class TestClass
  include TestModule

  def self.testSelfMethod
    str = module_method
    puts str
  end
  TestClass.testSelfMethod
end
```

Then it returns:

```
test.rb:11:in `testSelfMethod': undefined local variable or method `module_method' for TestClass:Class (NameError)
```

Comment: You could include the module in `TestClass`'s singleton class (`singleton_class.include TestModule`), but it amounts to the same thing as `extend TestModule`. In this example you could make `module_method` a module method of `TestModule` (`def  self.module_method; "module"; end`) and just invoke it from within the class (`TestModule.module_method`).

Comment: From @meagar♦, it seems I was trying to do something that doesn't make a lot of sense. I finally decided to drop this approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By including the module, you make `module_method` is an *instance* method on `TestClass`, meaning you need to invoke it on an instance of the class, not the class itself.

If you want to make it a method on the class itself, you need to `extend TestModule`, not `include` it.

```
module TestModule
  def module_method
    "module"
  end
end

class TestClass
  extend TestModule # extend, not include

  def self.testSelfMethod
    str = module_method
    puts str
  end
  TestClass.testSelfMethod # "method"
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I know extend module can solve the problem(as the question mentioned) but I can't do that in my project.

Comment: That makes no sense, you *have to* do it in your project, otherwise your project is wrong. You can't invoke instance methods without an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just because comments are too few characters, but agree with [maegar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225836/5239030):

```
module TestModule
  def module_method
    "module"
  end
end

class TestClass

  def self.testSelfMethod
    str = module_method + " from class"
    puts str
  end

  def testSelfMethod
    str = module_method + " from instance"
    puts str
  end
end

TestClass.extend TestModule
TestClass.testSelfMethod # => module from class

TestClass.include TestModule
TestClass.new.testSelfMethod # => module from instance
```